# OBJECT > EXPAND is disabled!

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a photo on a .jpg format and I'm trying to use expand under object, but it is disabled. Anyone here would like to help me why and how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: You can't expand a raster image. What is it you are expecting to happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can only expand a vector and you are talking about a rasterised image.
**First press live trace and only then expand.**